# How to make pages inside of a window using pyqt *designer*

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, designer

So Im in my pyqt designer and I was wonder how can I make it so when a button is clicked it will turn into a different page.

I want to know how to make this in the **pyqt designer** so if anyone can help, please do

[So I have a bunch of stuff on the side bar and I want to know how to make it so when one of them is clicked they will change to a different pagem, for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5SZV.png)

[Image you open the app and you see a punch of stuff in the front, and when clicked on another button, it will switch to a different page with different contents in the front.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDYT4.png)

Comment: Use QStackedWidget, then change the contents by connecting the buttons to functions that call [`setCurrentWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#setCurrentWidget)